# Remotely disable Macbook Air through network access

Tags: macos, security

My Macbook Air was stolen. The stolen Mac is showing up in Baku, Azerbajan.
I don't have the skill to do it myself, but I could imagine that there would be a way to do something nasty. Perhaps a script or some exploit. Something that would give some sort of notice or a flash dialog.

I know the computer still logs into gmail and dropbox by looking at the logs, so I've decided to not change those passwords as I have nothing worth protecting on those accounts as much as I'd want to get the Mac back or erased.

In case anyone has a solution I would appreciate any advice except "forget it!".

Comment: Since you know the "brother" is looking at your gmail ! send your self a email (from another account (a fake one)). What you say in it it is up to you ;)

Comment: I did that a few times. No reaction. I even uploaded (thru Dropbox) 3 Gb of videos of my self "politely" asking to at least contact me. Even promised to payback whatever the user paid for it. As far as I could understand, the user didn't even notice that he downloaded 3Gb of stuff from somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you had logged in iCloud in your computer you can trace it with that by logging on iCloud.com and then in the find my iPhone tab there you can Do any of the three options,

1. Show a message on the screen,
2. Remotely lock the computer
3. Clear the data from the computer.

P.S. In any case there is rare chance you may get it back so at the end you have to "forget it"

Comment: I hate to advise forgetting too, but unless the Mac had remote log in or iCloud (or similar) remote lock / remote erase functionality enabled - the chances of engineering a takeover by putting some "virus" or similar malware onto the dropbox / gmail account is going to need a highly skilled engineer / cracker.

Comment: I know about iCloud. Thanks. It wasn't on, otherwise I wouldn't be here. Remote login, on the other hand might have been on. I was developing web-apps and some of the servers might have been starting automatically. So there might be SSH or FTP access. The problem is I don't remember the port numbers. I tried scanning the ports, but it seems there is a firewall somewhere along the way and I can only see 80. Need a skilled-hacker-volunteer!!!